# Turning off device music on launching your application

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer, cocos2d-android

I am developing and app which has a background music. The issue i am facing now is that if i play a song on my android device and then start my app, the music plays in the background and also my app background music starts along with it.
Both music files play. All i want to do is override my app music over the device music already playing.
Is there a AudioSessionCatergory to select from just like iOS?

What i can do to solve this problem as i am using Cocos2dx.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong, but you just need to get audio focus at `onResume()` of your app's `Activity`. You may get it using `AudioManager`

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html#RequestFocus) is article for more info.